# BeanCreationException, NoSuchBeanDefinitionException found for same service jar in feature branch but not in master branch code

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml, javabeans, bean-validation

I am facing bean creation issue while deploying feature branch. However, same bean is found when building and deploying the master branch code. The only difference in master branch and my feature branch code is few pom file changes related to selenium dependencies. No changes are done the service dependency jar version & both are pointing to the same. 
However, I still face this issue only while deploying through feature branch. What could be the reason and how can i trace the issue ?

Both master & feature branch when tried to deploy refer the same jars/beans for the project.

````
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'tokenSecurityFilter' defined in class path resource [security-context.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tokenStorage' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:```
````

Comment: from error it seems `tokenStorage` is not included in your dependencies which is referenced inside `tokenSecurityFilter` .

Comment: Need more info to help here. Clearly there is some code/dependency missing in your feature branch. Find the source of the tokenSecurityFilter and try adding it to the classpath.

Comment: I found the solution to it. tokenStorage was registered in a bean using spring profiles in my project. so i added it in my web xml and the issue was gone.